# after getting access_token from facebook graph

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I can access access_token, but now I am sitting at:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=ID&redirect_uri=http://www.EXAMPLE.com/Home/FBTempIndex/&client_secret=SECRET&code=CODE-CODE-CODE#_=_`

and On this page, I can see:

```
access_token=ACTUAL-ACCESS-TOKEN&expires=5130106
```

That's all. I am no longer accessing this page from my server. How can I do that?

My requests end at FB servers. I confirmed it via Google Analytics and Fiddler. Here's fiddler image:

[image]

for better understanding, how can I request `GET me?acc...` when user is no longer on my website?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You take that access_token you get back then use it to query the Graph API.

Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: In the end all I am able to see is a white page with `code block 2` and location = `code block 1`. I don't know how can I use that data on my MVC application. This is `graph.facebook.com\...` not `mysite.com/something`.

Comment: You call the OAuth, from your webapp, using WebClient or something similar. You don't redirect the user's of your webapp through that process. As you can see on the image you added, all this communication is done between Your App and Facebook, the user's browser has nothing to do with that part of the authentication process.